# Laravel 5 Nested Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following table I can't use Order `hasMany` Product b/c Product don't have a foreign order_id.  I want to access everything through Invoice, is that possible?

I try to use `Has Many Through` but that is a A->B->C Relationship, I think want I setup need A->B<-C Relationship.

users table

```
|  id  |
```

invoice table

```
|  id  |  user_id  |
```

order table

```
|  id  |  invoice_id  |  product_id  |
```

product table

```
|  id  |
```

I wish to access all data through `invoice` table

INVOICE MODEL

```
class invoice extends Model {
    public function user() {  
         return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function order() {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
    }
}
```

ORDER MODEL

```
class Order extends Model 
{
    public function invoice()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Invoice');
    }
}
```

PRODUCT MODEL

```
class product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
    }
}
```

Comment: These relationships do *NOT* necessarily have to be opposites.  The only major difference between them is their default behaviours for constructing queries.  I would recommend defining your foreign keys explicitly instead of letting Eloquent do them for you.

Comment: I did define it explicitly in my migration file, I guess I just think if there is a way to use it in blade such as `@foreach($invoice->order() as $order) {{$order->product->id}}`.

Comment: Yes that's possible, migrations and eloquent are two separate things do not confuse the two.  Your problem is you need to forget about the invoice, and worry about `Order` and `Order\Line` or unless you map products to orders directly; then make a relationship between Order and Product.

Comment: Thanks that did shed some light. I was too focus on what I want to get it done.

Comment: `Order` can `belongTo` the `Product`.  If you think it should be a `hasMany` which I think makes more sense to me anyway, then you should change the schema.  Looks like you should remove `product_id` from `orders` and create a new table called `order_product` which has `order_id` and `product_id`, then you'd have a `belongsToMany` relationship between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your models should look like according to the schema.

INVOICE MODEL

```
class invoice extends Model {
    public function user() {  
         return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function order() {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
    }
    public function products() {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'order', 'invoice_id', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

ORDER MODEL

```
class Order extends Model 
{
    public function invoice()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Invoice');
    }
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
}
```

PRODUCT MODEL

```
class product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';

    public function orders()
    {
    public function products() {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Invoice', 'order', 'product_id', 'invoice_id');
    }
}
```

If this is not what you want, you will probably need to change the schema.

Comment: can you give example how I can loop through all the products given an invoice? now I am accessing the database with each `foreach` that is bad for performance.  is there a better way?

Comment: ```foreach ($invoice->products as $product) { ... }``` should only execute two queries. If you load multiple invoices, eager load products with ```App\Invoice::with('products')```

Comment: Actually, I just see that your schema is a many to many relationship. Need to edit the answer!

Comment: I redid my schema, make the database name follow the naming convention.  hopefully this will all work out.  but Many to Many should be the way to go. Thanks.